# Subversion visual tree

Tags: svn, clearcase

I'm used to work with ClearCase where I can see a visual representation of the code base in a tree structure view.

Do we have a similar tree for visual representation of SVN repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: the **[version tree](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_version_tree.htm)** in ClearCase displays the history of both files and directories (since a directory records the files added or removed in it), each time it is committed.

[image]

The [Subversion Revision Graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html) (also available as an [Eclipse plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/graph.html)) will display similar history, but sometimes with several nodes for a single revision:

> First-time users may be surprised by the fact that the revision graph shows something that does not match the user's mental model.
>   **If a revision changes multiple copies or branches of a file or folder, for instance, then there will be multiple nodes for that single revision.**
>   It is a good practice to start with the leftmost options in the toolbar and customize the graph step-by-step until it comes close to your mental model

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's called the "Revision Graph". You can find it using the TortoiseSVN client's menu.